# automatically update marker google maps v3

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

Good afternoon, I created a map that fills markers with coordinates directly from my mysql database, the map is being generated correctly and markers work when I load the page. Every minute I get new coordinates in the bank and want to update the map with a time interval. For this I used the setInterval that calls the initialization function of the markers, however, are not creating new markers on the map, is always displaying the same, they only update when I give f5 on the page, ie if reloading the page works, but with no interval. He even winked on the map when the time set by the interval, but not updated.

My code:

```
    <script src="js/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
 <?php
     if($attmap_form > 0) {
         echo 'myTimer = window.setInterval(refreshMapa,"'.$attmap_form.'");';
     }
 ?>
 function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.4848801,-49.2918938),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    locations = [];
    <?php
        require('conecta.php');
        $sql_lista = ("SELECT MONITLATITUDE,MONITLONGITUDE,MONITDATA,MONITHORA,MONITRAIO,MONITPROVEDOR,MONITVELOCIDADE FROM MONITORAMENTO where MONITHORA BETWEEN '$hora1_form' AND '$hora2_form' AND MONITDATA BETWEEN '$data1_form' AND '$data2_form' AND EQUIPIMEI = $imei");
        $query_lista  = mysql_query($sql_lista);
        $achados_lista = mysql_num_rows($query_lista);
        while ($achados_lista = mysql_fetch_array($query_lista)) {
            $lat = $achados_lista['MONITLATITUDE'];
            $lon = $achados_lista['MONITLONGITUDE'];
            $Data = $achados_lista['MONITDATA'];
            $hora = $achados_lista['MONITHORA'];
            $raio = $achados_lista['MONITRAIO'];
            $provedor = $achados_lista['MONITPROVEDOR'];
            $velocidade = $achados_lista['MONITVELOCIDADE'];
            echo 'locations.push ( {Data:"'.$Data.'", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng('.$lat.', '.$lon.'), hora:"'.$hora.'", raio:"'.$raio.'",provedor:"'.$provedor.'",velocidade:"'.$velocidade.'"} );';
        }
    ?>
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var markers = [];
    for(var i=0;i < locations.length;i++ ) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locations[i].latlng,
            map:map,
            title:locations[i].hora
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        bounds.extend(locations[i].latlng);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(
                 '<strong>Data: ' + locations[i].Data + '<br>Hora: ' + locations[i].hora + '<br></strong>Velocidade aproximada: ' + locations[i].velocidade + ' K/H<br>Raio aproximado de: ' + locations[i].raio + ' metros <br>Provedor: ' + locations[i].provedor + '<br>Latitude: ' + locations[i].latlng
              );
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
       })(marker, i));
    }
    markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
      maxZoom: 16,
      gridSize: 60
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
arrancaMapa();
function arrancaMapa() {
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}
function refreshMapa() {
   initialize();
   arrancaMapa();
}
function clearMarkers() {
     setAllMap(null);
}
function stopTimer() {
    $("#campoAttMap").val("0");
    clearInterval(myTimer);
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to call initialize more than once. You should implement a different logic, for example get the newest marker that is not in the map and add it via

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: locations[i].latlng,
        map:map,
        title:locations[i].hora
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    bounds.extend(locations[i].latlng);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(
             '<strong>Data: ' + locations[i].Data + '<br>Hora: ' + locations[i].hora + '<br></strong>Velocidade aproximada: ' + locations[i].velocidade + ' K/H<br>Raio aproximado de: ' + locations[i].raio + ' metros <br>Provedor: ' + locations[i].provedor + '<br>Latitude: ' + locations[i].latlng
          );
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
   })(marker, i));
```

**UPDATE:**

I will add take the following approach. I don't like mixing PHP and Javascript together, I prefer using JSON and AJAX request.

Update your functions to look like this:

```
var map;
var markers = [];

setInterval(refreshMapa, 3000);

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.4848801,-49.2918938),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var locations = [];

  $.get("getmarkers.php", function(response){
    for(var i = 0; i < response.markers.length; i++) {
      var marker = response.markers[i];
      var myMarker = {
        Data: marker.Data,
        latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lon),
        hora: marker.hora,
        raio: marker.raio,
        provedor: marker.provedor,
        velocidade: marker.velocidade
      };

      locations.push(myMarker);
      addMapMarker(myMarker);
    }
  },'json');

  markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    maxZoom: 16,
    gridSize: 60
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function refreshMapa() {
// make sure this one only returns markers that are new and not in the map
$.get("getnewmarkers.php", function(){
 for(var i = 0; i < response.markers.length; i++) {
   var marker = response.markers[i];
   var myMarker = {
     Data: marker.Data,
     latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lon),
     hora: marker.hora,
     raio: marker.raio,
     provedor: marker.provedor,
     velocidade: marker.velocidade
   };

   locations.push(myMarker);
   addMapMarker(myMarker);
 }, 'json');
}

function addMapMarker(myMarker) {
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myMarker.latlng,
      map:map,
      title:myMarker.hora
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    bounds.extend(myMarker.latlng);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<strong>Data: ' + myMarker.Data + '<br>Hora: ' + myMarker.hora + '<br></strong>Velocidade aproximada: ' + myMarker.velocidade + ' K/H<br>Raio aproximado de: ' + myMarker.raio + ' metros <br>Provedor: ' + myMarker.provedor + '<br>Latitude: ' + myMarker.latlng);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

PS: I'm not sure if the implementation of the addMapMarker is correct I just assumed you had it right in the first place, you should check the documentation and make sure it is correct.

Comment: @WouterFlorijn you are right that was not going to solve the problem. But it was part of the solution. I updated my response so that he could follow the idea better

Comment: I tried to adapt but it did not work, see my code:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fc49579a745ca6a9b679 - this create json: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b297927d25a3ffc4542a - link json create: http://www.crmdistribuidora.com.br/monitoramento/site/gera_json_coordenadas.php

Comment: Create JSON [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b297927d25a3ffc4542a) - my code: [link] (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d6169bdad4f16eec3d0c) - json link: [link](http://www.crmdistribuidora.com.br/monitoramento/site/gera_json_coordenadas.php) - the map does not open :(

Comment: @JuniorMaia the script that outputs JSON should one print out JSON remove the <HTML> and other tags. The file should start with <?php on the first line

Comment: [new create](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0700c18e23a74ffe6bc2) - [map not open](http://www.crmdistribuidora.com.br/monitoramento/site/index2.php)

Comment: @JuniorMaia you should change pontos to markers or vice versa and the page you linked is missing the jquery library

Comment: sorry brother, I change: [new create json](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/132411a0e0a13e5801fe) - [new php](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/42196824df3d49cd6f64) - [list json](http://www.crmdistribuidora.com.br/monitoramento/site/gera_json_coordenadas.php) - but it is not solving, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @JuniorMaia try the following code, it should work. [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/69fd23615dc4041a24cd)

Comment: Man, I love you! very very very nice! <3

Comment: it is not working and the infowindow or clusters, should we change a call?

Comment: @JuniorMaia the infowindow is not being initialized anywhere so you need to look in the documentation and/or the samples in the google maps api pages. as for the cluster you need add a function call to add markers to the cluster inside the addMapMarker() function

Comment: hey brother, how do I pass data to the PHP variables in this function: $.get("GERA_JSON_COORDENADAS.php?imei=357627051445616&data1=2014-10-06&data2=2014-10-06&hora1=00:00:01&hora2=23:59:59", function(response){

Comment: @JuniorMaia from GERA_JSON_COORDENADAS.php you can use $_GET['imei'] which holds the value 357627051445616 and so on.

Comment: hey brother, I adapted the code and it worked correctly, added the points, clusters and infowindow, however, the setContent is repeating in all infowindow all lie with the latest information received .. Can you check for me? [this new code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/39d083883552c759d528)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so the thing is, PHP is a server-side language that only gets executed when the page loads. I'm not sure exactly how you would expect your JS to update the markers, as there are no get/post anywhere. If you want to get data from the server, you have to contact the server.

This loop

```
    while ($achados_lista = mysql_fetch_array($query_lista)) {
        $lat = $achados_lista['MONITLATITUDE'];
        $lon = $achados_lista['MONITLONGITUDE'];
        $Data = $achados_lista['MONITDATA'];
        $hora = $achados_lista['MONITHORA'];
        $raio = $achados_lista['MONITRAIO'];
        $provedor = $achados_lista['MONITPROVEDOR'];
        $velocidade = $achados_lista['MONITVELOCIDADE'];
        echo 'locations.push ( {Data:"'.$Data.'", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng('.$lat.', '.$lon.'), hora:"'.$hora.'", raio:"'.$raio.'",provedor:"'.$provedor.'",velocidade:"'.$velocidade.'"} );';
    }
```

Only gets executed ONCE. The value of `locations` doesn't change.

You should read up on jQuery ajax requests. Make an HTTP request to a PHP file that returns the locations as JSON (just echo the JS array) and use the result to update the markers.

Comment: can you tell me if this is correct JSON format: http://www.crmdistribuidora.com.br/monitoramento/site/gera_json_coordenadas.php

Comment: Looks like that's correct. It's basically the same way you would notate arrays in Javascript.

Comment: I can make a reference link directly with the json generated without generating .json file on the server? Something like this works? var json = (function () {
            var json = null;
                $.ajax({
                    'async': false,
                    'global': false,
                    'url': "http://www.crmdistribuidora.com.br/monitoramento/site/gera_json_coordenadas.php",
                    'dataType': "json",
                    'success': function (data) {
                     json = data; } });
                return json;})();

Comment: Yes something similar to that should work (not sure if that function would do the job but you can test it).

Answer (score 0):

Reason:
There is no update function (or code blocks) to get updated or newly added DB info in your code. Also, you will not read and add new db info to your map data because your PHP code is only called once at initialization-time.

Using PHP codes, you will not do it because of the PHP features. PHP will only work on back-end service sides.

Suggestion: 
1. You need client-side updates to access service side updates and receive them.
2. You need to add the updated or newly added db data to your Marker (map) array on client sides.

For this, 
1. Add client side update features in AJAX or others to update the info to JSON objects.
2. Call the AJAX block (retrieving block or function to read in JSON object array and add them to map marker arrays).
3. Update null pointer of Map Markers to the new Map array.

Sorry for not creating a working code set based on your codes. It will take a fairly long while.

Comment: plumb so I'm grateful for the time you took writing your suggestion, thanks! :)